# Relocationg Floating Action Button by user

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, floating-action-button

Lastly I found tutorial with Floating Action Button example.

Link: http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-floating-action-menu-example.html

Now I would like to allow user to move action button to any place on a screen. Then, he might open it and select one of the option.

Last time I did very the same thing with View objects instead of FloatingActionButton object and it worked perfectly. With FloatingActionButton it didn't come off.

I did two attemps.

1) In first one I set setOnTouchListiner to LayoutInfater object (like in my View example) but then the only thing I could do is to swipe the screen left or right and then button moved slightly to the right or left. When I touched the button and then moved - nothing happened.

2) I also tried to set setOnTouchListiner directly to FloatingActionButton but it doesn't even show up.

How can I let user to move that FloatingActionButton?

Here is code with View objects and below my attempt no. 1 with FloatingActionButton.

One more remark: FlyingButton extends Service and MaterialDesingDialog extends Activity. That is on purpose. In general I want to have button over the all system icons. Since MaterialDesingDialog doesn't work as I want I extended Activity class as I suspected that the problem is in extending Service.

**View objects**

```
public class FlyingButton extends Service {


private WindowManager windowManager;
public Dialog dialog;
View layout,dialogLayout;
int ciekawyX, ciekawyY;

ImageView button1,button2,button3,button_cross;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

   setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;

    windowManager.addView(layout, params);


    try {
        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            float move_X_axis,move_Y_axis;

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        //Log.e("ACTION_DOWN","1");

                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //Log.e("ACTION_UP","2");

                        if( (move_X_axis < 0.1) && (move_Y_axis < 0.1)  ) {
                            if (layout.getWindowToken() != null) {
                                //windowManager.removeView(layout);
                                Log.e(""+move_X_axis,""+move_Y_axis);
                                CustomDialog();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //Log.e("ACTION_MOVE","3");

                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(layout, paramsF);

                        move_X_axis = event.getRawX() - initialTouchX;
                        move_Y_axis = event.getRawY() - initialTouchY;

                        ciekawyX = paramsF.x;
                        ciekawyY = paramsF.y;

                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
}


public void CustomDialog(){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogbox, null);


    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    params.x = ciekawyX;
    params.y = ciekawyY;


    if(layout.getWindowToken() != null) {

        windowManager.removeView(layout);
    //}

    //if(dialogLayout.getWindowToken() !=  null){
        windowManager.addView(dialogLayout, params);
    }


    button1 = (ImageView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.e("BRAWO","KLIKNALES BUTTON1");
        }

    });

    button2 = (ImageView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.e("BRAWO","KLIKNALES BUTTON2");
        }

    });

    button3 = (ImageView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.e("BRAWO","KLIKNALES BUTTON3");
        }

    });


    button_cross = (ImageView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.cross_button);

    button_cross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            if(dialogLayout.getWindowToken() != null) {
                windowManager.removeView(dialogLayout);
                //}

                //if(dialogLayout.getWindowToken() !=  null){
                windowManager.addView(layout, params);
            }
        }

    });


}

}
```

**FloatingActionButton**

```
public class MaterialDesingDialog extends Activity{

FloatingActionMenu materialDesignFAM;
private WindowManager windowManager;
View inflatedMaterialDesignDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflatedMaterialDesignDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.material_design_dialogbox, null);

    materialDesignFAM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.material_design_android_floating_action_menu);


    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;

    windowManager.addView(inflatedMaterialDesignDialog, params);

    try {

        inflatedMaterialDesignDialog.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            float move_X_axis,move_Y_axis;

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        Log.e("ACTION_DOWN","1");

                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.e("ACTION_UP","2");


                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.e("ACTION_MOVE","3");


                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                        move_X_axis = event.getRawX() - initialTouchX;
                        move_Y_axis = event.getRawY() - initialTouchY;

                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(inflatedMaterialDesignDialog, paramsF);

                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this type of floating button in my project. I think your issue is due to `LayoutInflater`. Don't set view containing floating Button  in `WindowManager`. Set Floating Button directly to your `WindowManager`.

Following is my code, which worked well for me:

```
public class notificationService extends Service{

private WindowManager windowManager;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
FloatingActionButton Abutton;
Context context;
public FloatingActionMenu menu;
private final IBinder noteBind = new NotificationBinder();

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
    return false;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return noteBind;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    Abutton = new FloatingActionButton(this);
    Abutton.setProgress(0,true);
    Abutton.setColorNormal(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.floatingButtonColor,null));
    Abutton.setColorPressed(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.floatingButtonColorPressed,null));
    Abutton.setColorRipple(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.floatingButtonColorRipple,null));


    Abutton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.pause_note);
    Abutton.setX(25);


    Abutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    //set onclick events here
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                // Handle your onClick event here.

        }
    });


    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;


    windowManager.addView(Abutton,params);  //directly add your floating button here.


    try {
        Abutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        // Get current time in nano seconds.

                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(Abutton, paramsF);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (Abutton != null) windowManager.removeView(Abutton);
}
}
```

I've implemented this button programmatically only. So there is no xml layout for this. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work. Button even doesn't show up. 
I also couldn't find methods you set to button. It is: setProgress(), setColorNormal(), setColorPressed(), setColorRipple(). These can not be resolved. Maybe we talk about different Floating Action Button?

Comment: https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton  I've implemented this floating button. And I found that also in your link, this button is described. Have you added proper dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I added it.

    `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'

    }`

Comment: then what is the problem? can you add error log or something?

Comment: That was my fault. I imported android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton instead of com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton. Now methods are seen but when it comes to getColor method it says: `Error:(68, 47) error: non-static method getColor(Resources,int,Resources.Theme) cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: I've changed the way I set the color. As all method needs int argument I set directly color from R.id.WHATeverCOLOR. It is `        Abutton.setColorNormal(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        Abutton.setColorPressed(R.color.colorPrimary);
        Abutton.setColorRipple(R.color.colorAccent);`

No errors but also no button on a screen. 

Here is code:

http://pastebin.com/t4t1NCX6

Comment: if you have android SDK >=23 , than you have to go to your apps permissions and enable the `Draw_overlay` permission for your particular app/

Comment: and are you sure that you are starting service correctly?

Comment: Oh my goodness.. I missed that I had to add proper service note in AndroidManifest... `    <service  android:name="com.example.komp.floatingbuttonpowtorka.MaterialDesignDialogService android:exported="true" />` What a noob I am... Finally moves. :) Thanks a lot for patience!